# Time-out with the Vimeo python module

Tags: python, vimeo-api

I'm having severe issues using the Vimeo API and the most simple syntax for upload with their python wrapper:

```
v = vimeo.VimeoClient(token, key, secret)
about_me = v.get('/me')
assert about_me.status_code == 200
print(about_me.json())
try:
    print("Upload {}...".format(nomFichier))
    video_uri = v.upload(fichier)
```

And then I get that error once in a while (but still like 90% of the time):

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='1511923755.cloud.vimeo.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)
```

What's going on ? I'm in a while True: loop, that monitors a watched folder so I don't know if maybe I'm making too many requests, but in the playground I can see that I still have X-RateLimit-Remaining: 90
So I'm not sure what's going on…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so to make things clear, if you're using the python code from vimeo, just kow that the upload completion is not handled. So you have to handle exceptions, like that :

```
def changeNameOnVimeo(vimeoAcces, URI, name):
    success = True
    while success:
        try:
            vimeoAcces.patch(URI, data={'name': '{}'.format(name)})
            print("Video renommée sur Viméo.")
            success = False
        except (ReadTimeout, ConnectTimeout, ConnectionError) as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Video renommée sur Viméo.")
            success = False
```

I'm not sure the while = True loop is mandatory, but I love those.